# Laravel serialize models with åäö for job in redis queue throws error

Tags: serialization, laravel-5

I have a basic job which takes a number and a message and then stores this. Everything works fine unless the message contains Swedish characters like åäö then I end up with the following error:

```
exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined index: job' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php:125
```

This is what my job looks like

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Jobs\Job;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Log;    

class QueueIncoming extends Job implements ShouldQueue
    {
        use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

        private $number;
        private $message;

        public function __construct($number, $message)
        {
            $this->number = $number;
            $this->message = $message;
        }

        public function handle()
        {
            Log::info("QueueIncoming: started");
        }
    }
```

**How can I store characters like åäö in the Laravel job?**

Comment: I forgot to mention that the $message here comes from an external service via an API. I believe that could have helped solve my issue quicker.

Answer (score 0):

SerializesModels in Laravel 5.2 will support åäö as long as they are using UTF-8 encoding. If you run into this error chances are that your åäö characters are using ISO-8859-1 encoding or perhaps some other encoding.

The solution to my problem would be to simply use utf8_encode() on the text that may have åäö.

```
$this->message = utf8_encode($message);
```